# Why is MySQL not accepting this value, or why is php not transmitting it properly?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a contact form for my company, and I made this large elaborate form with over 20 fields for the user to fill out.  Upon clicking submit, the php page sends an email to a sales rep with a detailed report of the order.  The next step is to get the info into a database.  I wrote the code for it, but it is not working, so I created a secondary table for me to use for testing purposes until I am ready to use the one for the company.  In this small test database, there are 3 fields, orderID, companyName, and contactName.  When I specify an orderID, and only an orderID, it gets stored in the database, no problem, using the code below.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("host", "username", "pass", "dbname");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $mysqli->query("insert into testTable (orderID) values (5000)");
```

But if I use this code below, this time including a companyName value, nothing happens at all.  I get no errors(that I see) and php says nothing.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("host", "username", "pass", "dbname");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $mysqli->query("insert into testTable (orderID, companyName) values (5000, \'".$_POST['companyName']."\')");
```

Any and all help is appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: And if you change it, like this : $mysqli->query("insert into testTable (orderID, companyName) values (5000,'".$_POST['companyName']."')");

Comment: Add some error reporting to your code, specifically after you run `$mysqli->query()`. It is highly likely that you have an SQL syntax error

Comment: Have you checked all your logs yet? something could be failing silently.

Comment: Are you asking me to do that?  Ill go ahead and do it, but shouldn't i have to escape the single quotes?

Comment: Sorry if this is a nooby question, i just started learning mysql yesterday, but how do i check the logs? Or add error reporting?

Comment: The _webserver_ log (specifically, the error log).

Comment: Im looking at the error logs(i think) but they are very vague and reference place on the site that have not existed for months, and I see nothing about mysql in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("host", "username", "pass", "dbname");
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$companyName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['companyName']);

$mysqli->query("insert into testTable (orderID, companyName) values (5000, '$companyName')");
```

I think you were escaping the single quotes and it wasn't necessary, also I sanitized your company name to help protect you against MySQL injections.

It is best to use prepared queries none the less, for more information, visit the following links :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: it says mysqli_real_escape_string() requires 2 parameters

Comment: should be $mysqli->real_escape_string

Comment: It says 
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/content/33/9093333/html/geotest/process.php on line 125

Comment: I edited it twice, is the line really " $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['companyName']);" ?